# python 2.5.2 multiprocessing pool behavior

Tags: python, module, multiprocessing, pool

When attempting to divide a DB insertion up between cores using the python multiprocessing module on 2.5.2, CentOS 5.5, the entire pool of 16 processes aborts as soon as the first one finishes.  I thought that using pool.close/pool.join was supposed to prevent this very thing from occurring.

```
def insert():
    blocksize=lines/ncpus
    i=0
    while i<lines:
        print 'writing block %d to %d' % (i,i+blocksize+ncpus)
        pool.apply_async(write_db, (i,i+blocksize+ncpus,query,))
        i+=blocksize+ncpus
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def write_db(start,stop,q):
    ctr=0
    odbcstring"...."
    con = pyodbc.connect(odbcstring)
    cur = con.cursor()

    commitlock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    for j in range(start,stop):
        try:
            cur.execute(q[j])
            ctr+=1
            if (ctr%10000)==0: 
                commitlock.acquire()
                con.commit()
                commitlock.release()
        except:
            print get_exception_info()         

    commitlock.acquire()
    con.commit()
    commitlock.release()
    con.close()
```

I am theorizing that it has something to do with this sentence from the pool.apply [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool):
Additionally, the passed in function is only executed in one of the workers of the pool

Perhaps there is some difference between built-in MP and the MP module that I'm not aware of.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say it "aborts as soon as the first on finishes", what exactly does "aborts" mean?  Is there an error?  Are you sure all the other expected processes are even running?  Have you tried adding some logging/print statements to debug it?

Comment: I have confirmed that each of the processes is running by inserting debugging statements prior to each commit and by verifying that data is indeed being written to the DB.  It does not end with an error; all of the running processes that don't complete are simply killed.  Additionally, I've noted that sometimes more than one process completes by inserting a final print statement at the end of write_db.  Thanks for your continued help.

Comment: Try wrapping a try/except clause around `all` the code in the write_db method (and print out any exception that occurs).  If there were some sort of database issue (like max connections exceeded), it could result in what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with your issue, but you're creating a **new** multiprocessing.Lock object in every process you create.
...so acquiring this lock around your connection commits isn't going to do anything.

[**EDIT**] In order to share this lock between processes, you need a manager object:

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
lock = manager.Lock()
```

Now you should be able to pass this lock as an argument to your processes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried running the same code with the locks simply commented out with the same result, so I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: This worked well to establish locks.  I never did get the pool to work, though, and just used individual processes instead.